# How do I map one variable's values to another variable in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

In my Grafana dashboard (with Prometheus as a data source), I have a custom `$tier` variable, which allows the user to pick the tier from a dropdown. It's defined as:

```
Values separated by comma: production, stage, development
```

I need to filter a Prometheus metric by a label which contains a *shortened* version of the tier name:

- "foo-dev"
- "foo-stage"
- "foo-prod"

I was thinking that I'd create a hidden variable `$shortened_tier` so I could use that in my query filter, like this:

```
my_label=~"foo-$shortened_tier"
```

I'd like to define it based on the value of `$tier`:

- "development" -> "dev"
- "stage" -> "stage"
- "production" -> "prod"

How do I do that?

Comment: https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-alias-a-template-variable-value/10929/2?u=jangaraj

Comment: Thanks @JanGaraj, can you clarify how that would work here? My `$tier` variable has hard-coded values; it isn't pulling from a data source like prometheus metrics. Is there some way to create my `shortened_tier` variable as a query variable that references `$tier` (or `[[tier]]`?) and use regex to only select the first N characters?

Comment: No, you need to save your relations in some DB first and then query it via hidden variable. You can't do a variable string manipulation in Grafana.

Comment: Can I create a *query* variable for `shortened_tier`, where the query is just `$tier`, and use a regex like `/(....).*/` to only keep the first 4 characters?

Answer (score 7):

I figured out a workaround for this, but it is suuuuper hacky:

```
Name: shortened_tier
Type: Query
Data Source: Prometheus
Query: label_values(up{env="$tier"}, env)
Regex: (dev|stage|prod).*
```

What I wanted to do was simply `Query: $tier`, but since Grafana wouldn't let me do that, I had to use a completely different metric (`up`) where I could pass in `$tier` and get back *the same exact value* as a string. Then I use regex to just look for `dev|stage|prod` at the beginning of the string, capture that part, and throw away the rest.

This has the result that I'm looking for, with the value of `$shortened_tier` dynamically changing based on the value that's selected and assigned to `$tier`. But *man* I wish Grafana had a less hacky way to do this.